# Python Discord_Bot, Chatgpt_api: API request: 400 Client Error: Bad Request

Tags: python, discord, openai-api, 400-bad-request

I am pretty new to coding, but i have been struggling for some hours on this and i can't seem to figure out how to make this to work. So, basically the project i am coding right now is a discord bot with a touch of chatgpt_api in it. And i keep getting the same error (Error making API request: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions) and when i try to fix the error in the code everything "crumbles" into a bunch of error after error. So i am at a stage where i don't want to change anything because the normal functions works, such as sending pre written messages.

I have tried changing the "main" api request code to what i have found searching around the internet, i have also tried using the code Openai themselves say you should use. According to them this was for a "simple" api call, but it never worked out for me in the end. I have also checked other threads but found nothing that have helped.

```
completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "What are some famous astronomical observatories?"}
  ]
)
```

My code may be a like a shot in the dark towards making it work.
**But, Here is the whole code.**

```
import discord
import requests
import os
from openai import OpenAI

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
clientAI = OpenAI(api_key=os.environ['CHATGPTKEY'])

api_key = 'CHATGPTKEY'
api_url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'
curl = 'curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ' + 'api_key'


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith(
      '!hello'
  ):  
    await message.channel.send('Hello!'
                               ) 
  if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello')('!')

  if message.content.startswith('!help'):
    await message.channel.send(
        'Harald is Goat, you can trust Harald!\n' 
        '\nGeneral Commands:'
        '\n\n!hello - Says hello to you'
        '\n!help - Shows this'
        '\n!hr - Harald shall respond to you'
  print(message.content)

  if message.content.startswith('!hr'):
    user_message = message.content[50:]

    try:

      response = requests.post(
          api_url,
          json={
              'messages': [{
                  'role':
                  'system',
                  'content':
              }, {
                  'role': 'user',
                  'content': user_message
              }]
          },
          headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_key}'})
      response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an error for HTTP errors

      # Get the model's response
      model_response = response.json()['choices'][100]['message']['content']

      # Send the response to the Discord channel
      await message.channel.send(model_response)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
      print(f"Error making API request: {e}")
      await message.channel.send(
          "An error occurred while processing your request.")


try:
  token = os.getenv("TOKEN")
  client.run(token)
except discord.HTTPException as e:
  if e.status == 429:
    print(
        "The Discord servers denied the connection for making too many requests"
    )
  else:
    raise e
```

Here is also the dependencies:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
openai = "^1.9.0"
requests = "^2.31.0"
discord-py = "^2.3.2"
```

I would appreciate some explaination if possible.

Thanks in advance!